# Get elevation of an area

Tags: matlab, matrix, area, elevation

I need to get the elevation in meters, of specific points within in a 1km square of ground.
Each point will be 5 meters apart, meaning a total of 40,000 specific points.
The elevation for each of these points will be stored in a 200x200 matrix.

I have tried to use the Google Maps Elevation API, but I think the amount of data I need to request will exceed the terms of service.
I also need to use the elevation data on Matlab, but reading the terms of service for the Google API, I believe I would be limited to using the data within Google Maps itself.

Please could you suggest a solution for me?

Comment: You should be fine with the amount of data you need to request from Google, as you can submit up to 512 sets of coordinates with each request, and up to 2,500 requests can be sent a day - meaning a total of just over 1.2 million sets of coordinates can be requested a day.

However, you are correct in that you cannot use the data without plotting it on and displaying a Google Map.

I have no experience with matlab, but I cannot see any issue with you throwing the data through matlab, as long as you also display a google map with the elevation data marked on it at the end - even if it's unused..

Comment: Note that if you start and end your grid at the corners you will actually want 201x201 data points.

Comment: @SK93: thank you for the help, about the problem of plotting, maybe it's related to who wants to use these contents on a website or an application, not for personal use. So to cover the whole matrix maybe I can submit some requests every day.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: sorry I don't understand you, I would have a matrix 200x200, where 200 are columns or rows and in the position 1,1 I set the first coordinate, so 200x200 :)

Comment: I tried to state that if you want to cover a length of n*X it usually requires n+1 points. BUT regardless of this, judging from the comment by SK93 it should just be possible to pull the data. I would recommend you to try and update the question if you encounter any difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the Terms and Conditions for Google's elevation API, I believe you would be fine in using it for PERSONAL use in Metlab.
However, if you intend to publish the results or anything derived from the data, you will need to include a google map with it... but that could be in the form of a link to a map with just the 200x200 points plotted - a fifteen minute job to knock up ;)

Go for it :)